# Override Class Attribute, with a generic way to refer to class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django abstract Model.

```
class Company(models.Model):
   DEFAULT_EMPLOYEES = None
   employees = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, 
                                           default=<<<what_goes_here>>>.DEFAULT_EMPLOYEES)
   class Meta:
       abstract = True

class BestBuy(Company):
   DEFAULT_EMPLOYEES = 1000
```

I am interested in overriding a class attribute to use as a default value.  I was wondering if there was a generic way to refer to the class to make this possible.  In `Company` I realize I can refer to attribute using `Company.DEFAULT_EMPLOYEES`, but is there a way like: `"CurrentCLass".DEFAULT_EMPLOYEES`.

I'm pretty sure `self` cannot work here, because there are no instances in these definitions.  Just the classes

Is there a better way to approach this to allow children classes to specify a default value?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Why not just define the field in every model? To do what you want will probably be cumbersome and error prone, you will need to dig deep into Django's metaclass capabilities

Comment: You'd probably be able to do things like that with `inspect.currentframe()` and so on.. but that's a nonsense to do, if you're just doing it to avoid writing the attribute one more time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach would be to replace the save function to set employees if it's blank at the time of saving.

Something like:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kw):
       if self.employees is None:
            self.employees = self.DEFAULT_EMPLOYEES
       super(Company, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

the define `DEFAULT_EMPLOYEES` in each child class as you have done.

The alternative is modifying the metaclass which is probably overkill.

Comment: Might not be a good solution, `save()` [is not called](http://goo.gl/GmuhcS) from `bulk_create()` and I don't think that this approach will work with Django's sync command, south, and the serialization infrastructure.

Comment: Not good in every situation, but it would be fine for 99% of applications. Not a great solution, but the best simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Define a classmethod on your parent:

```
@classmethod
def showDefaultEmployees(cls):
    return cls.DEFAULT_EMPLOYEES
```

Then just call it from your class instance

```
BestBuy.showDefaultEmployees()
```